# Catching exceptions in EitherT and preserving underlying monad transformers

Tags: haskell

Basically I want to understand how to do exception handling. I'm using the `exceptions` package with `MonadThrow`/`MonadCatch` and this isn't making a lot of sense to me. I broke it down into the smallest example that I could. I appreciate this is pretty contrived.

First I define an arbitrary `Exception`:

```
data ReadLineException = ReadLineException deriving (Show,Typeable)
instance Exception ReadLineException
```

Then there is a function which asks the user for a number, and keeps track of what happened using a MonadWriter. If a number isn't entered it throws an exception using `throwM` from `Control.Monad.Catch`.

```
ioTell :: (MonadWriter [String] m, MonadIO m, MonadThrow m) => m Int
ioTell = do
    tell ["Some opening string"]
    liftIO $ print "Enter a number: "
    x <- liftIO $ getLine
    let mx = maybeRead x :: Maybe Int
    case mx of Nothing -> do
                    tell ["Invalid entry was chosen: " ++ show x]
                    throwM ReadLineException
               (Just a) -> do
                    tell ["Number chosen was " ++ show a]
                    return a
```

Next, I define some way to arbitrarily catch any exception (supposing that the rest of the computation can continue regardless of any exception):

```
eitherCatch :: (Monad m, MonadIO m, MonadThrow m, MonadCatch m) => EitherT SomeException m a -> EitherT SomeException m a
eitherCatch et = catchAll et (\e -> left e)
```

With the general types out of the way, I define a Transformer stack with an escape function:

```
type MyExcept a = EitherT SomeException (WriterT [String] IO) a

runMyExcept :: MyExcept a -> IO (Either SomeException a,[String])
runMyExcept me = runWriterT $ runEitherT me
```

Finally I run `ioTell` twice in a row, collecting the outputs from both writers and merging them (in my actual usecase this is complicated further because I use `async` and `wait`).

```
testM :: MyExcept Int
testM = eitherCatch $ do
    (ex,w1) <- liftIO $ runMyExcept ioTell
    let x = case ex of (Left _) -> 10
                       (Right a) -> a
    (ey,w2) <- liftIO $ runMyExcept ioTell
    let y = case ey of (Left _) -> 10
                       (Right a) -> a  
    tell $ w1 ++ w2 ++  ["Combined value is " ++ show (x + y)]
    return (x + y)
```

This didn't catch the exception. Console output:

```
"Enter a number: "
2
"Enter a number: "
x
(Left ReadLineException,[])
```

With some trial and error, I worked out that I can get the error handled by running `eitherCatch` before I run `runMyExcept`. This way the exception is thrown into a `Left` constructor before trying to pattern match on it (seems so obvious now, though there was no way to infer that the program would escape purely from thetypes):

```
testM :: MyExcept Int
testM = do
    (ex,w1) <- liftIO . runMyExcept $ eitherCatch ioTell
    let x = case ex of (Left _) -> 10
                       (Right a) -> a
    (ey,w2) <- liftIO . runMyExcept $ eitherCatch ioTell
    let y = case ey of (Left _) -> 10
                       (Right a) -> a  
    tell $ w1 ++ w2 ++  ["Combined value is " ++ show (x + y)]
    return (x + y)
```

**First problem**: this loses the state built up by the `Writer` by the function that throws the exception:

```
"Enter a number: "
1
"Enter a number: "
x
(Right 11,["Some opening string","Number chosen was 1","Combined value is 11"])
```

**Second problem**: this also seems to force where the exception is handled. Suppose I wanted the entire computation to fail, the moment one computation failed. I hoped that the exception would proliferate up through the call stack, and could be caught anywhere along the chain.

Assuming I can find some resolution to the first problem, I think my only choice is then to `tell` as soon as the values come in and use `hoistEither` to prevent the rest of the computation for continuing:

```
testM :: MyExcept Int
testM = do
    (ex,w1) <- liftIO . runMyExcept $ eitherCatch ioTell
    (ey,w2) <- liftIO . runMyExcept $ eitherCatch ioTell
    tell $ w1 ++ w2
    x <- hoistEither ex
    y <- hoistEither ey
    tell ["Combined value is " ++ show (x + y)]
    return (x + y)
```

Then `hoistEither ex` could be moved above the subsequent call to `ioTell` preventing it from executing, or moved further down to allow both to happen.

Finall, if I specialise `ioTell` to `ioTell :: MyExcept Int` and use `left` instead of `throwM` then all of this works fine. I don't have to worry about an unchecked exception and the `WriterT` gets preserved. Which is fine for this toy example where the exception was manually generated. But what about in general?

Comment: I'm not sure `throwM` and `EitherT` together does what you need here, since e.g. evaluating `runEitherT (throwM ReadLineException :: EitherT ReadLineException ())` results in an error instead of a `Left ReadLineException` value... The documentation for the `MonadThrow` instance of `EitherT` explicitly mentions that it "[t]hrows exceptions into the base monad."