# Catching Haskell exceptions with gi-gtk and Reactive Banana

Tags: haskell, gtk3, frp

My application is bug-free, of course, but just in case it contains any bottom values I want to put in a generic exception catcher which will at least pop up a message box to tell the user what kind of bug to report. Because I'm using [gi-gtk](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk) I figured that any exceptions after initialisation will happen from inside the `Gtk.main` function, so the end of my `main` function looks   looks something like this:

```
let executeProgram =
     catch Gtk.main $ \e -> do
           reportThisBugDialog $ show (e :: SomeException)
           -- Code here to try to recover to a known good state
           executeProgram
executeProgram
```

I'm also using [Reactive Banana](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana) in case that is relevant, but this is outside the FRP code.

However this doesn't capture any exceptions. I put `error "Test Exception"` in the handler for "Help About", and my program just exited with a message printed to the console (which my users will not see of course).

How do I catch exceptions that occur inside my code when it is reacting to GTK signals?

Comment: Great question. I suspect you're going to have to wrap each callback in a handler, as I believe callbacks get run in fresh Haskell threads (though still on the same OS thread as `main`, assuming `Gtk.main` itself is). Can you check whether that works for you? (I know it sucks...)

Comment: @DanielWagner Its actually worse than that: almost all my callbacks do nothing more than fire off a Reactive Banana event. Quite what happens next in terms of call stacks and exception handling I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727644/how-to-catch-a-haskell-exception-that-is-thrown-in-a-haskell-callback-function-c) (though it is not specific to `gi-gtk`, so is a bit more general)t. Also I'd recommend [this](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com.by/2017/11/haskell-exceptions-and-ffi-wrappers.html) post.

Basically, haskell exceptions can't pass haskell/C border. Simply because C doesn't know anything about haskell exceptions.

In your case, `Gtk.main` runs `gtk` event loop, which is implemented in C, and callbacks are implemented in haskell. When callback throws haskell exception, it has to go through `gtk` event loop in order to reach `executeProgram` function. But it is impossible for the reason stated above.

I'm afraid, the solution is to catch all exceptions inside each callback. In your case, you probably can write a wrapper over `on` function from `gi-gtk`, which will catch all exceptions and show the bug dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will try the wrapper you suggest.